# Promises Code Review

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have just started playing with nodeJS and I try to get familiar with promises.

I have the code bellow and for me it looks like it can be improved by moving the **retry** logic and put it inside getValue2.

*Retry logic is different than the getValue2.*

The problem is that as soon as I put the logic inside the method, getValue2 finishes before retryGetValue2's promise finishes.

Ideally, I want to remain just with line 
**sendPriceResponse(res, res2);**
and get rid of the if-else

Any recommendations?

This is the code:

```js
getValue1(link).then( function(res)
{
  getValue2(link2).then(function(res2)
  {
    if(res2==='') // retry logic <===---------------|
    {                                             //|
      retryGetValue2(link2).then(function(res2new)//|
      {                                           //|
        sendPriceResponse(res, res2new);          //|
      });                                         //|
    }                            //_________________|
    else
    {
        sendPriceResponse(res, res2);
    }
  });
 });
```

getValue2 looks like :

```js
function getValue2(link)
{
 return getInfo(link); // returns a promise
}
```

Comment: Use async/await instead of promise https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function 

Promise is a hell https://medium.com/@pyrolistical/how-to-get-out-of-promise-hell-8c20e0ab0513

Use async/await https://blog.risingstack.com/node-js-async-best-practices-avoiding-callback-hell-node-js-at-scale/

Comment: Why is `The problem is that as soon as I put the logic inside the method, getValue2 finishes before retryGetValue2's promise finishes.` a problem? Isnt that exactly what the code is supposed to do?

Comment: @JaromandaX and Quentin, please take a look at the [Code Review help center](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). This question would be **off-topic** at Code Review.

Comment: Why? It's an MCVE and stripped of all context. At CR, we need context.

Comment: @JaromandaX You recommended the site anyway. Don't redirect questions to sites if those sites don't want them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your retry logic can be as easy as:

```
 const getInfoRetry = link => getInfo(link).then(res => res ? res : getInfoRetry(link));
```

That will not only retry once but as lojg as it gets a valid response. Now just do:

```
getInfoRetry(link1).then(res =>
  getInfoRetry(link2).then(res2 =>
     sendPriceResponse(res, res2)
  )
);
```

You could also get them in parallel:

```
 Promise.all([getInfoRetry(link1), getInfoRetry(link2)])
  .then(([res, res2]) => sendPriceResponse(res, res2));
```

Comment: After reconsidering, this is exactly what I was looking for.
Thanks! What I don't get is here
".then(res => res ? res : getInfoRetry(link)" In case there is no res, call the retry method, but if the res exists, we return res (which is not a promise). So how can we use .then after it?

Comment: @claudiuSocaci its promises flattening behaviour. Calling `.then` returns a promise itself, which will resolve to what you return from the inside, or if that is a promise, it will resolve to what that promise resolves to. So in conclusion: `getInfoRetry(link).then(res => ...)`

Comment: YFYI: I could have written it as `.then(res => res || getInfoRetry(link))` but I thought that would just confuse anyone ...

Comment: I actually used @CertainPerformance's solution on top of this solution and now it looks even better. thanks all!

Comment: @claudiuSocaci well his solution is overly complicated ... Whatsoever: glad to help :)

Comment: thanks for the last edit. I am really happy about the result after refactoring. His solution is more complex but I like the idea of getting rid of indentation.

Comment: Nah if you replace simple code with complex code for the sake of getting less indentation ...

Answer (score 1):

You should chain the promises together to avoid the promise-as-callback anti-pattern, which results in indentation hell; instead, `return` each `Promise` in the chain.

When you want to pass along a value (such as `res`) in addition to waiting for a `Promise` to resolve (such as your `getValue2)`, use `Promise.all` to pass an array of both the value and the promise. Similarly, in the next function, you can use `Promise.all` to pass an array of both `res` and either the `retryGetValue2` or the `res2`, depending on whether `res2` is falsey:

```
getValue1(link)
  .then((res) => Promise.all([res, getValue2(link2)]))
  .then(([res, res2]) => Promise.all([
    res,
    res2 || retryGetValue2(link2)]
  ))
  .then(([res, verifiedRes2]) => {
    sendPriceResponse(res, verifiedRes2);
  });
```

If `res2` can possibly be falsey but *not* the empty string, then you'll have to use the conditional operator instead of `||`:

```
Promise.all([
  res,
  res2 === '' ? retryGetValue2(link2) : res2
])
```

Comment: I like this approach! Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

```
const getValue2WithRetry = (link) => {
  return getValue2(link).then((res2) => {
    if(res2 === ''){
      return getValue2WithRetry(link);
    }else{
      return res2;
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23803743/what-is-the-explicit-promise-construction-antipattern-and-how-do-i-avoid-it